# How to set default value for select in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this:

```
  <select class=" text-center form-control" name="custname"
            ng-model="a.custid" 
            ng-init="devcustname[0].customer_name"
            ng-change="fetchassocd(a)">

     <option value="" selected="true">Please select a Customer name</option>
     <option ng-repeat="a in devcustname | orderBy:['customer_name']"
            value="{{a.customer_id}}">{{a.customer_name}}
    </option>
  </select>
```

I want the default value to be `devcustname[0].customer_name`. The ng-init is not working. When the `devcustname[0].customer_name` is null or undefined I want the "Please select a Customer name" to be displayed as default.

If I use `ng-options` I can't show the "Please select a Customer name"".

Comment: `ng-init="devcustname[0].customer_name || a.custid = ''"` and `<option value="">Please select a Customer name</option>`

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov `ng-init` just doesn't work even when there are values.

Comment: what are the values in devcustname?

Comment: @Sajeetharan see this http://jsfiddle.net/oxjvcef0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope){
   $scope.devcustname = [
    {customer_id: "3", customer_name: '', customer_email: "fas@gmail.com", contact_no: "23", address_line1: "6, f4"},
    {customer_id: "4", customer_name: "ab", customer_email: "sm", contact_no: "12", address_line1: "R V Road, 10th cross"},
    {customer_id: "5", customer_name: "da", customer_email: "3a@gmail.com", contact_no: "33", address_line1: "6, f4"}
  ];   
  $scope.a = {custid: "4"};
})
```

```html
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>
  <select class="text-center form-control" name="custname" ng-model="a.custid" ng-init="temp = devcustname[0].customer_name || (a = {custid:''})" ng-change="fetchassocd(a)">
    <option value="" ng-disabled="isDisabled">
     -Please select a Customer name-
    </option>
    <option ng-repeat="a in devcustname | orderBy : 'customer_name'" value="{{a.customer_id}}">
      {{a.customer_name}}
    </option>
 </select>  
</div>
```

Comment: @Nobody, is my answer provides proper/desired behavior?

Comment: @Nobody, I reproduced your plunker at my answer.